# SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open backup device Operating system error 5(Access is denied.)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

Hy I am getting sqlException while trying to backup SQL Server database programatically in ASP.NET core in hosted application. Backup works properly on local maching but after deploying it is throwing SQL exception.
My code is

```
string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()+".bak";
var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot","DatabaseBackups", fileName);               
System.Console.WriteLine(filePath);
string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
var query = $"BACKUP DATABASE MySchool TO DISK='{filePath}'";
using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
 conn.Open();
 var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 Logger.LogInformation("BackUp Completed");
 conn.Close();
}
```

If its permission issue on the server, I have given full permission to wwwwroot folder in server.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here; the SQL Server service account does not have access to the backup location.

Comment: What is the value of _filepath_? And does your user have access rights on that folder?

Comment: yes i user have access right. user can upload photos and all..

Comment: Are you aware that the SQL Server service might be running with its own user account? (For example, when I look at the service on my own machine, it says it runs with user account "NT Service\MSSQLSERVER".) Are you really sure that you have indeed provided sufficient access rights to your wwwroot folder your specific SQL Server service user? This error message is typically indicating that the SQL Server service is not allowed to access the target location for your backup.

Comment: Your current logic appears to assume that the application is running on the same machine as your server instance. How else would the current directory of your executing application be accessible to the server instance? As already indicated - you need to provide a path that the server instance service account can access.